# Issue with Google Apps Script form.setDestination - produces "unable to load file" error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have Google Spreadsheet which creates a form and then attempts to link the form response destination to another sheet in itself. All has been working absolutely fine for a while, but it has suddenly started producing the error "Unable to load file" whenever I run the script. It then requires that I reload the form and crashes the rest of the script.

I've narrowed down the line producing the error to the call of the form.setDestination method specifically:

`form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());`

I see that this error has been logged as an issue with Google here:https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6793&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner but are there any workarounds or ways that I could get my sheet working again as it's broken some functionality that I needed.

Thanks for your help and advice!

UPDATE:
I have now replicated the issue across multiple accounts (and multiple browsers/internet connections), here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BZQVNRjK-OOZbRfOdTlhXYKLt2519CG6d_B7TYn1rGo/edit?usp=sharing

Just click the big red button on the "control" sheet...
(I think my sharing settings allow you to view the script behind it, but see below if not)

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// create form with appropriate name
var form = FormApp.create("abcdef");
// Set destination of responses to new tab in current spreadsheet
// Option to send form responses to spreadsheet
form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());

var textItem = form.addTextItem();
textItem.setTitle('Text box example');
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the code you have now, sets up a situation where you don't need to write any extra code.  I think that you're only option is to manually put some new code in either the new Form or the spreadsheet, and then use and "On Form Submit" trigger.  Then create some code that sets the Form data in that other sheet tab.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but unfortunately that doesn't apply to my situation, I have a script that creates a custom form, populating data from spreadsheet fields and then sends a link out to multiple respondents. We then aggregate the responses (they're all numeric) into a summary sheet and add the new form's data to the summary metrics every time we run the script. Manually adding code to each form isn't possible for the application I need to use this for unfortunately.